# How to replace a image with another image after clicking a button in angular 6?

Tags: html, css, angular6

I have a button which consists of a image & name. On clicking of that button I need to replace the image & content. I have given my code below.

```
<div class="btn-default">
  <button name="Save" [ngClass]="[bntStyle]" (click)="submit()">
   <img class="img1" src="./image1.png"/><a 
   class="sidebarlinks" >Content1</a>
  </button>
</div>
```

Likewise I have few more buttons.

My ts file:

```
 submit() {
   this.bntStyle = 'btn-change';
}
```

My css file:

```
.btn-change {
 background-image: url("./image1_after_click.png");
}
```

Can somebody help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove [] from ngClass value

```
<button name="Save" [ngClass]="bntStyle" (click)="submit()">
```